# Title is not showing in master detail page menu

Tags: menu, xamarin.forms, navigation, master-detail, titlebar

I have implemented a hamburger menu using master detail page in my Xamarin app.

Referred  [this link](https://almirvuk.blogspot.in/2016/10/how-to-make-master-detail-page.html)

I'm trying to display the title "Dashboard" by default in the action bar and after that the name of page navigated from the menu will display over there.

The solution that I found according to that given title to all pages then why is is not showing that navigated page title in action bar.

Any help most appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a look at the page you referred and I can't see the page title being set anywhere.

One way to do it is to change the code in OnMenuSelected

from

```
Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page));
```

to

```
var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(page);
page.Title = item.Title;
Detail = new NavigationPage(page);
```

Comment: thanx steve.it worked for me.actualy i had set  title from xaml page.dont know why that was not workinng

Comment: seeking for one more help. how can we display it in center.?any idea?

Comment: Display what in the center?

Comment: page title now showing  at left after icon in action bar.how can we display it in center?

Comment: The only way to change the placement of the title text is through a custom renderer. It is probably best to leave as is as people expect a particular OS to display the title a specific way.